# JPAUpdateClause - is it possible to concatenate string values when setting values?

Tags: java, querydsl, mysema

I'm using JPAUpdateClause to update all rows satisfying a BooleanExpression where clause.

```
BooleanExpression where = myEntity.id.isNotNull();
long updatedCount = update.where(where)
        .set(myEntity.comments, request.getComment())
        .execute();
```

myEntity.comments is a String.

Is it possible to append request.getComment() when calling set() rather than replacing the existing value?

Comment: What do you want to append it to ?

Comment: The existing comment in the database.  So if before executing this query the database has some value the new value is just added onto the end.  Maybe append would be a better way to ask

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting `request.getComment()`, try something like below

```
Expressions.operation(String.class, Ops.ADD, myEntity.comments, request.getComment())
```

Comment: Hi Ashishkumar, thanks for the help! I think you're on the right track with your answer, but I'm one thing.  The params for Expressions.operation are Type, Operator, and Expression.  How would I represent the two values, myEntity.comments and request.getComments as an Expression?